# get_terms() - unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) error

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to get the terms from all the taxonomies in an array. but this throws an error like this ..not sure why. Is it the wrong method?:

> Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting
>   ',' or ')'

```
public function pggggo_list_of_terms(){
    $terms = get_terms(
      'taxonomy' => array(
                     'vehicle_safely_features',
                     'vehicle_exterior_features',
                     'vehicle_interior_features',
                     'vehicle_extras')
    );  
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: You forgot about `array(` before `'taxonomy'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PHP syntax error. You're attempting to pass an array to `get_terms()` but haven't used `array()` or `[]` to make it an array. This means that `=>` is invalid here. The code should be:

```
public function pggggo_list_of_terms() {
    $terms = get_terms(
        [
            'taxonomy' => [
                'vehicle_safely_features',
                'vehicle_exterior_features',
                'vehicle_interior_features',
                'vehicle_extras',
            ],
        ]
    );

    return $terms;
}
```

or

```
public function pggggo_list_of_terms() {
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => array(
                'vehicle_safely_features',
                'vehicle_exterior_features',
                'vehicle_interior_features',
                'vehicle_extras',
            ),
        )
    );

    return $terms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to do this. Passing arguments is wrong in your code.

```
public function pggggo_list_of_terms(){
    $terms = get_terms(
      'taxonomy', array(
                     'vehicle_safely_features',
                     'vehicle_exterior_features',
                     'vehicle_interior_features',
                     'vehicle_extras')
    );
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid call a [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/):  Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args array.